# The equation $r = 3\cos(\theta)$ in polar coordinates describes a line in the plane. True or false?

Tags: plane-geometry

Just as the title describes. Is it true or false? I know it is a line in 2D, but circle in 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r=3\cos\theta\implies\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, or $x^2-3x+y^2=0$ where $(x,y)$ is the cartesian coordinates of the point $(r,\theta)$. $x^2-3x+y^2=0$ is not the equation of a straight line. In fact it is the equation of a circle centered at $(3/2,0)$ with radius $3/2$. $$\left(x-\frac32\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac32\right)^2$$

[image]

Comment: $\cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. The factor $3$ comes from $3\cos\theta$.

Comment: I forgot  the denominator. Thanks!